# EventListener Failing with Long code, why?

Tags: javascript, html

It should fill the field but it does nothing, why?

```
<html>


<input type="button" id="phoneButton">
<input type="text" id="allQuery">


<script>
  // catch CLICKING with mouse to fill the text field
  var input = document.getElementById('phoneButton')
  input.addEventListener('click', function(e) 
  {
    document.getElementById('allQuery').value = 'hello' 
  }, false)


</script>

</html>
```

**[Update]**
...my point was not really the typo, I have more code like this but much longer and for some reason such addEventListeners do not notice the objects with which they are used with (such as the phonebutton). What is the problem with longer code? How to make sure the eventListeners have loaded vars so that they do not get cleared from the cache with long code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById` is a method of `document`, not global function.

Also make sure the `#phonebutton` element exists when Javascript runs; `DOMContentLoaded` event is often helpful.

Comment: how can you make sure the "phonebutton" element exist? I have this problem without the typo "missing document" in larger code and it does not work, apprently missing phonebutton or something like that? Perhas cache cleared? How to know whether phonebutton element exist? What do you mean by DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: @hhh If you support just browsers that support `addEventListener`, use `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* your code here */ }, false);`. This causes that the code will run after the entire markup is transformed into DOM tree. To do this in browsers that don't support `addEventListener`, the easiest solution is to use simple `window.onload` event or use some framework that resolves cross-browser issues - jQuery is quite popular; its equivalent to `DOMContentLoaded` is `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code here */ });`.

Comment: but I use `someVar.addEventListener('someEVent', func, false)` how does it know to look for certain event without specifying the event? I created eventListener for click and keydown, how to create the eventListeners for them in your way? I have massive problems currently due to event listeners, the objects such as phonebutton do not exist apparently with eventlisteners (althoug they in reality exist)

Comment: what about if you have two eventListeners? Do you create many DOMContentLoaded things or just one for all eventListeners?

Comment: @hhh It is also a valid option, but you can put the entire code into single DOMContentLoaded event handler.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4242/discussion-between-duri-and-hhh)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm you should do a `document.getElementById('allQuery').value = 'hello'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep in right format of HTML

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="phoneButton">
<input type="text" id="allQuery">


<script type="text/javascript">
  // catch CLICKING with mouse to fill the text field
  var input = document.getElementById('phoneButton')
  input.addEventListener('click', function(e) 
  {
    document.getElementById('allQuery').value = 'hello'; 
  }, false);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, `head` and `body` have optional opening and closing tags and no browser requires the `<script type>` attribute. Your markup is equivalent to OP's.

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener does not work with all browsers. I recommend using a js platform which abstracts the inconsistencies with event binding across browsers like jquery.